# utf-8 Codification, strange characters, GUI doesn't work

Tags: python, c, user-interface, tkinter, utf-8

I am developing a MQTT app that takes some values through a board and bring it to a GUI. So I programmed also in C and in python (for the GUI).
I have a problem with UTF-8 codification.
In C I wrote it:

```
   sprintf((char*)diagnostic_payload, "{\"Diagnostic response: \%X %X %X %X %X %X %X %X %X}", frameRead.can_id, frameRead.data[0], frameRead.data[1], frameRead.data[2], frameRead.data[3]
, frameRead.data[4], frameRead.data[5], frameRead.data[6], frameRead.data[7]);
            
            size_t payloadLen = sizeof(diagnostic_payload);

            const le_result_t publishResult = mqtt_Publish(
            MQTTSession,
            newTopic,
            diagnostic_payload,
            payloadLen,
            MQTT_QOS0_TRANSMIT_ONCE,
            retain);
            if (publishResult == LE_OK)
            LE_INFO(
                "Message published");
```

It works good, I see the message on the command prompt of the broker on Windows, but I can't understand why, some strange characters are added:

[image]
I wrote an app that brings this value on a graphic interface:
client = mqtt.Client("Prova")

```
m_decode = ''




def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print("log: "+buf)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        print("Connected OK")
        connection_status.config(text="Connection status: CONNECTED")
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code = ", rc)
        connection_status.config(text="Connection status: BAD CONNECTION with error" + rc)

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, flags, rc=0):
    print("DisConnected result code "+str(rc))
    connection_status.config(text="Connection status: DISCONNECTED" + rc)

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    topic=msg.topic
    global m_decode
    m_decode=str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    print("message received", m_decode)
    testo_receive.configure(text=m_decode)
    #testo_receive.config(text="Messaggio ricevuto on diag_response: " + (m_decode))
    #Le righe sotto vanno aggiunte se vuoi memorizzare i dati su file di testo
    file = open("documento_test_diagnosi.txt", 'a')
    file.write(m_decode)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    

#questa funzione, tramite il tasto send, invia un messaggio su un certo topic (in esempio, mangoh)
def publish_message(client, msg_entry):
    msg=msg_entry.get()
    msg_entry.delete('0', 'end')
```

it works for a normal string of char, but with the string I mentioned above it doesn't work, obtaining this error:
[image]
Could the cause of the issue be the codification? Can someone help me to understand where am I wrong?
Any help will be appreciated,
Kevin

Comment: Well first of it works, ok, it works as You have coded it to work, it doesn't mean it works as You wish but it certainly works, second it is clear to me that utf-8 encoding does not have those characters so it is throwing an error, try decoding in a different format or sth also it has nothing or very little to do with tkinter and more with strings although I may not be correct about this particular nuance.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why on the command prompt I see the stirng that doesn't stop, but continues with strange characters...is there a reason?

Comment: Probably some bytes that it cant decode so it places what it thinks should be there or just skips those or throws an error or places a symbol or sth. It just doesnt know what to do

Comment: You need to use `payloadLen = strlen(...)` instead of `payloadLen = sizeof(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you for the advice. I tried but I have and error with the strlen: `pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'strlen' differ in signedness [-Werror=pointer-sign]`

Comment: OK guys. I tried to put `(char*)...)`, it works, but I see only the first three characters, or rather `{"Di` :(

Comment: Could you add how you defined diagnostic_payload? It seems strange that you pass a cast

Comment: Of course.  `uint8_t diagnostic_payload[64];`

Comment: You can cast the type like `payloadLen = (size_t) strlen(...)`.

Comment: Solved,  `size_t payloadLen = strlen((char*)diagnostic_payload+1);`

Comment: Should it be `size_t payloadLen = strlen((char*)diagnostic_payload)+1;` instead (include the NULL character as well)?

Comment: ah you right yes, sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the problem is

```
size_t payloadLen = sizeof(diagnostic_payload);
```

You are getting the size of the buffer, not the size of the string. Note: Python allow you to use any Unicode character, also `\0` in text. This was used in past for padding, or just as "non-character" on terminal which specified speed, but data not ready.

So you send data with dirty trailing bytes, which python try to print, but because they are random numbers and not valid UTF-8 sequences, you have the error.